# How to get a c# user control property to browse for a URL at design time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Some ASP.NET controls have properties that allow you to browse for a URL like so:
[image: browse for url]

How do I do that?
This is my property so far:

```
[Category("Video Attributes")]
[Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor", typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public Uri VideoLocation
{
    get { return _vidLocation; }
    set { _vidLocation = value; }
}
```

I can see and edit the property and if I type a URL myself, it works. But it sure would make life easier if I could browse for the URL. Better still would be if it could default to a specific folder.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Just going to wrap up this question with example code

```
private String _tutorialFile = "";
```

...

```
[Category("Linked Files")]
[UrlProperty(), Editor(typeof(System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor), 
    typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public String TutorialFile { get; set; }
```